FFmpeg 5 -> FFmpeg 7 results in color differences in decoded raw video
We have been using ffmpeg 5 to decode h264/h265 video to yuv420p rawvideo and things work well. We are looking into updating to ffmpeg 7, but noticed that the colors in the rawvideo are different despite the command being identical.
I would like to figure out why this is happening and what additional args are necessary to restore the original colors
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -threads 2 -hwaccel_flags allow_profile_mismatch -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt -rtsp_transport tcp -timeout 5000000 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i rtsp://*:*@192.168.50.152/streaming/channels/101 -r 8 -vf fps=8,scale_vaapi=w=2560:h=720:format=nv12,hwdownload,format=nv12,format=yuv420p -threads 1 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p pipe:
I spent a good bit of time trying different colorspace color_range etc arguments as well as setting out_color_range on the scale_vaapi filter but it does not make any difference.
Here is an example gif showing it goes from ffmpeg 7 -> what it looks like in ffmpeg 5

Edit:
A video for testing
Some additional info after comments:

this issue does NOT occur when using the software decoder and software scale filter.
this issue DOES occur when using ffmpeg ... -hwaccel_output_format yuv420p -vf fps=8,scale=w=2560:h=720 ... which I guess indicates it is an issue with vaapi hardware decoder specifically


Welcome to this site! Please note that your post does not actually contain a question. Please EDIT it to focus on a single, specific question that we can try to find an answer to.

thanks, edited to add that, I am trying to figure out what changes are necessary in the ffmpeg command to restore the original output colors

Is it reproducible with synthetic input video? Try using input.mp4 as input. Generate it: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x216:rate=1:duration=10 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p input.mp4. Use input.mp4 as input: ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -i input.mp4 -vf scale_vaapi=w=2560:h=720:format=nv12,hwdownload,format=nv12,format=yuv420p -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p output.yuv

Great idea, I have tried a few different things.

I tried with an mp4 video that was created from the camera using -c copy and it does reproduce.
Tried with the synthetic video using the command you supplied and it does not reproduce.
I tried using your command but adding -color_range pc and it does reproduce (the camera input is also pc color range)


Is it reproducible with software decoder and -vf scale=2560:720? Is it reproducible with software decoder and scale_vaapi: -vf hwupload,scale_vaapi=w=2560:h=720:format=nv12,hwdownload,format=nv12,format=yuv420p? How about marking the stream as full/limited range: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=384x216:r=1:d=10 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=0 input_tv.mp4 and ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=384x216:r=1:d=10 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -bsf:v h264_metadata=video_full_range_flag=1 input_pc.mp4?

Can you please share a very short video recorded from your camera using -c copy (share using Google Drive for example)?

It does not reproduce with software decoder and software scale filter.
If I use the software decoder and scale_vaapi it seems something is wrong and the entire image is shifted as green.
I can't upload the original camera due to privacy reasons but you can find a different camera video which has the same issue at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HswVM67Dze1DB5kdr_ZskLcV7zY8Sr3V/view?usp=sharing

Try adding -color_range pc before the -i (forcing the decoder to apply the input as "full range"). I can't reproduce the issue (testest with FFmpeg 4 and 7)... Using MediaInfo tool, I saw that your sample video is marked strangely: there is a mix of BT.601 and BT.709. It could explain the color shift, but not the brightness shift (you may try fixing the metadata of the sample video using Bitstream Filter).

That did not help unfortunately. For transparency I am using https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds as the ffmpeg build. bsf can't be applied to an input, correct? in normal application it is run live on camera streams where latency and reduced cpu usage is a priority

Made an additional edit, the issue still occurs when using vaapi to output to yuv420p and using scale instead of scale_vaapi so it seems to be an issue with the vaapi decoder?

Does it happen with git master build?

Seems there is a bug or something in git master as I get implib-gen: libva.so.2: failed to resolve symbol 'vaMapBuffer2' via dlsym: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva.so.2: undefined symbol: vaMapBuffer2

Just tried ffmpeg 6 and the behavior is the same

also was able to try using nvidia for decoding and it has the same issue as well
